# JDBC connects with 'jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxx' but hangs and throw socket exception for 'jdbc:mysql://172.29.198.142:3306/xxx'

Tags: java, mysql, jdb

I have a very strange kind of problem here. JDBC connects to mysql server using '127.0.0.1' but when I use real IP-ADDRESS in that place it hangs like forever and throws some socket exception

so 
    "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/xxx"; works like a charm....

"jdbc:mysql://172.29.198.142:3306/xxx"; throws the below ugly Exception...!!

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver   has  not received any packets from the server.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1117)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:350)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2408)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2445)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2230)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:813)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
got null
com.xxxxxxxx.server.test.PersistTest
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:334)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
at com.lntinfotech.server.test.PersistTest.testConnectionJDBC(PersistTest.java:204)
at com.lntinfotech.server.test.PersistTest.main(PersistTest.java:56)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Malformed reply from SOCKS server
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.readSocksReply(SocksSocketImpl.java:90)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:429)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:259)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:300)
... 16 more
```

please help!!!!!!

Thanks in advance......

Comment: Your client is configured to use a SOCKS proxy which is preventing access to your combination of public MySQL IP address and port. You need to configure the proxy to allow this access.

Answer (score 0):

check if u open the port for network. Simple test you can use mySql Query browser in that PC or another PC in network but use the IP address not localhost or 127.0.0.1... if it can connect you can check java library or java code. if it cant you can check if there antivirus or firewall that block that port.